# Masstransit 3.5.7 causes leak in erlang processes & number of channels

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

we are using 
masstransit 3.5.7
rabbitmq 3.6.5

Our environment is running ~2000 microservices.
We use cluster.

We are experiencing a leak in the number of channels as well as the number of erlang processes being used.
In the image below you can see that we have ~46,000 channels.
If we look into the connections, we see there are many idle channels in each connection.

In addition, maybe related to it, we can see that the number of erlang processes is constantly increasing.

Can someone please share some information and assist with this behavior? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmryp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Erlang process yes it's related to opened channels, I simulated here opening thousands of channels (without masstransit, just a regular app) (and not closing by purpose) and look the result, similar to yours:
[image]

About the issue, possible it's related to:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/266

So you can try do this:

> it's necessary to setup a cleanup timer on the SendEndpointCache so
>   that unused endpoints are shut down after a few minutes.

Hope it helps.